# Python execute task

Tags: python, task

I have Python class with indefinitely blocking task method

```
class A(object):
   def __init__(self):
       # start task

   def task(self):
       while True:
           #do some work
```

I want to start execution of the task in constructor of A. It will probably need to be run in its own thread as the task is blocking. How to do that in Python 2.7?

Comment: You may use separate process (https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)

Comment: threading can be performed with the [threading](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned in comments, there's a module *threading* that seems to exactly fit your task. Example:

```
import threading

class A(object):
   def __init__(self):
       threading.Thread(target=self.task).start()

   def task(self):
       print 'Hello from a Thread'

a = A()

# output: 'Hello from a Thread'
```